# Error: Invalid Chai property: revertedWith

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, hardhat

I want to test my contract **FundMe.sol** but how it takes off **FundMe.test.js** an error pops up this

My console

```
FundMe
    constructor
Development network detected! Deploying mocks...
      ✓ Should set the aggregator addresses correctly
    fund

      1) Should fail if you don't send enough ETH


  1 passing (977ms)
  1 failing

  1) FundMe
       fund
         Should fail if you don't send enough ETH:
     Error: Invalid Chai property: revertedWith
      at Object.proxyGetter [as get] (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/proxify.js:78:17)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/FundMe.test.js:29:46)
```

the file where the test is written to the file **FundMe.sol**

***FundMe.test.js***

```
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect, revertedWith } = require("chai")

describe("FundMe", async function() {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator
    beforeEach(async function() {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"]) // deploy all contracts using deployment.fixture()
        fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer)
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            deployer
        )
    })

    describe("constructor", async function() {
        it("Should set the aggregator addresses correctly", async function() {
            const response = await fundMe.priceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, mockV3Aggregator.address)
        })
    })

    describe("fund", async function() {
        it("Should fail if you don't send enough ETH", async function() {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith("You need to spend more ETH!")
        })
    })
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to **install hardhat-chai-matchers** like this:

```
$ yarn add --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers
```

Or

```
npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers
```

And then **add this line** to your **hardhat.config.js**:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers");
```

More info: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `ethereum-waffle` to your packages. With `@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle` being installed it is not working!

```
yarn add --dev ethereum-waffle
```

Once done, you'll be able to use `revertedWith`.

Recent hardhat's new package hardhat-toolbox has replaced few basic packages [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomicfoundation-hardhat-toolbox)

Answer (score 2):

The revertedWith() is not actually a part of Chai, it comes from hardhat, make sure you have also set const {ethers} = require("hardhat") at the top of your script

for example:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { expect } = require("chai");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import `revertedWith`, that is what is causing your `Error: Invalid Chai property: revertedWith` error.

Try changing your chai import line to this:

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32686001)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120984/property-revertedwith-does-not-exist-on-type-assertion

**Post June 2022**

Install it with npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox or yarn add --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox and then import it in your hardhat.config.js like this

```
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox')
```

Comment: Thank you. only the last thing mattered to me as of today: require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'). This is a very dynamic situation. LOL

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```js
const chai = require("chai")             
const { solidity } = require("ethereum-waffle")
chai.use(solidity)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very dynamic situation as the interdependency changes so fast.

As of 2023/03/22, I ran

```
hardhat@2.13.0
chai@4.3.7
@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@1.0.6
```

To make expect(..).to.be.RevertedWith(..) work, I only needed

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers")
```

I DID NOT need

```
yarn add ethereum-waffle
yarn add @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
```